# SocketClients logged in with user tokens do not consistently receive Guild Member Update dispatches

Tags: c#, discord.net

I know support for user account was cancelled and has been for a long time, however, I have my purposes. Essentially the goal is to track the role permissions of one specific role that everyone in the guild has. Now it isn't always the same role but it is always the same name so essentially what I need to do is grab the before and after versions of "NAME" role, every time a user updates and the actual role changes. It's not for anything creepy I promise it's just to have a player tracker on a discord game.

However, my alt account that I use for user botting (because I don't want to be personally banned) does not receive GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE dispatches AT ALL. despite being in the guild and receiving MESSAGE_CREATE and MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD dispatches. My main account, so far as I can tell, receives them for all users, and works pretty much flawlessly as intended, but it is not something I want to keep running. My friend, when running the same script, gets the dispatches for some users but not others, on a seemingly random basis.

I have attempted downloading guild users on the READY dispatch which so far as i can tell runs successfully but solves nothing. And maybe there is no solution and it's just because user accounts aren't intended to be usable anymore regardless, but there's a reason I'm here instead of the github. Just curious if anyone else might have some solutions. Note that the alt in question is a fresh account that just joined the server, the friend joined a few months ago, and I've personally been in the server over a year now, so it may have something to do with how old the account is/how long ago the server was joined? The whole situation is unclear.

My apologies if you wasted your time reading this far and have not solution, there's a reason i mentioned it was a user bot first thing, in case that really is that only issue here. Since saying it's a user token causes a build error i just do `await _client.LoginAsync(0, token);` and it throws and exception and calls ready twice but aside from that seems to function as per usual but that may have something to do with it as well.

edit: to be specific on why it's in the discord.net tag, not only is that just where this particular bot is being made, but it just so happens that the concept works fine is discord.py, I just prefer working in a c# environment and already have all the rest of the necessary code written in it. My .py version is poorly made and not something I really want to have to rewrite.

Comment: Maybe I didn't read carefully enough, but _why_ exactly do you need a user bot for that?

Comment: @Twenty mmmmm because the server would not let me add a bot to it, I don't own the server, and it's nice to be able to run it through an account I can fully control. The server IS the game so a user account makes it possible for me to manually move the bot around the "map" if ever necessary for certain functions. But is there seriously no known cause? does it just do that? and might there be a better way to use a user token?

Comment: Alright, makes sense though. Anyhow you might need to write your own wrapper or search for a different library, since as you said yourself d.net doesn't support it anymore.

Comment: man @Twenty I'm glad you believe in me but dude Im literally NotThatSmart and dont have anywhere near the skills or knowledge I'd need to do that, considering I took like 2 hours just to figure out how to run an instance of Discord side by side with a Windows Form and allow the two to interact, I doubt writing my own Wrapper would be something I can do with my schedule. Thank you for the advice though!